# how to restore the cell size in excel range. office.js addin webapp

Tags: office-js

i am developing a office addin using office.js javascript library, i found that if i want to clear the formatting for a range, there is a clear method https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/range.md#clearapplyto-string
but this method doesnt restore the original sell size. i have increase the width and height of cell, and if i call this method, it just clears the formatting, but doesnt restore cell size. how to restore the cell size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call `range.format.autofitRows()` and `range.format.autofitColumns()`

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/rangeformat.md